# c# XAML - 2nd WPF window only responding after second touch click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a keypad as such :

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Name="btnTotal" Width="280" Height="60" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,10,10" Background="#302F37" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" FontSize="35"></TextBox>
    <Button x:Name="btnZzero" Content="0" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5,5,5,5" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White" Focusable="False"  Click="btn_Click"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnOk" Content="OK" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5,5,5,5" Click="btnOk_Click" Background="#FF8FC377" Focusable="False"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5,5,5,5" Click="cancel_Click" BorderBrush="Black" Background="#FFD64D4D" Focusable="False"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnOne" Content="1" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="14,6,0,6" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btn_Click"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnTwo" Content="2" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White" Click="btn_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnThree" Content="3" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White" Click="btn_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnFour" Content="4" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White" Click="btn_Click"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnFive" Content="5" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White" Click="btn_Click"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnSix" Content="6" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White" Click="btn_Click"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnSeven" Content="7" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,5,9,6" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White" Click="btn_Click"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnEight" Content="8" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White" Click="btn_Click"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnNine" Content="9" Width="80" Height="60" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" Focusable="False" Background="#302F37" Foreground="White" Click="btn_Click"></Button>
```

When I call this keypad to use for a username and password it works fine when clicking with a mouse.  But when I use the touchscreen monitor I have to click anywhere first inside the keypad window before it will accept the first button press. How can I solve this please?

```
//click inside user ID text box
    private void userIDTextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        userIDTextBox.Text = "";                            //clears text box text
        getKeyPadAndResult();                               //run helper method   
        userIDTextBox.Text = loginKeypad.QuantityResult;    //add text from keypad tologin screen


    }

    //Click inside password text box
    private void passcodeTextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        passCodeTextBox.Text = "";                            //clears text box text
        getKeyPadAndResult();                               //run helper method
        passCodeTextBox.Text = loginKeypad.QuantityResult;  //add text from keypad tologin screen
     }



    //*****first helper method***** to open keypad, remove default text from login textboxes and pass back numbers
    private void getKeyPadAndResult()
    {
        loginKeypad.QuantityResult = "";                    //resets text               

        loginKeypad.Owner = this;                           //opens login keypad
        loginKeypad.ShowDialog();
        loginKeypad.Focus();
    }
```

EDIT: So it turn out the reason it does this is due to the mouse over on the button not being enabled.  Because I select a TEXTFIELD which opens the keypad, the keypad opens over where I just clicked and there is no button highlighted.  If I roll over a button with the mouse then I can touch any button and it works straight away.  Otherwise I have to select a button first (to highlight at least one) and now I can touch any button. I have a feeling it may be still waiting on the textfield on the window before so that is why it only reacts to the second touch.

Comment: Apart from covering issue, use Style to get ride of repeating.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand this comment.

Answer (score 0):

OK this issue was being caused because I was using

```
private void userIDTextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

Instead of :

```
private void userIDTextBox_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

My keypad was being loaded when selecting the userID Textbox so I assume it was staying inside that text box until I selected the keypad again. By using the PreviewMouseUp to load the keypad then it was switching directly to my keypad window.